# Mostrar duplicados sin tener en cuenta los valores nulos

Tags: python, pandas

tengo un dataframe al que quiero extraer todas las filas que tengan un valor en una columna específica duplicada, en este caso la columna "DOI". Sin embargo, esta columna tiene varios nulos y me los cuenta como duplicados ¿Hay alguna forma de mostrar los duplicados "evitando" los nulos sin tener que eliminar estos?

Pongo ejemplo de dataframe:

| Autor | DOI |
| --- | --- |
| Ana | 23 |
| Sara | nan |
| Carlos | 23 |
| Pepe | 07 |
| Clara | nan |

Con este codigo
df['DOI'].duplicated().sum() me devuelve 4 duplicados porque cuenta los nulos, yo quiero que no me los cuente.

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Y cuál es el DataFrame???

Comment: Perdona, edito la pregunta

Comment: Si y agrega lo que has intentado